# How to convert time / date with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I currently have this

```
last_modified = xhr.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified');

/* Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Apr 2011 20:47:09 GMT */
```

However, for the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin i need this format

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

What would be the most easy and bulletproof way to convert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this using javascript as follows:

For the Title part:

```
    var dateObj = new Date(last_modified);
    var newDate = dateObj .getFullYear() + "-" + dateObj.getMonth() + "-" + dateObj.getDate() + "T" + dateObj.getHours() + ":" + dateObj.getMinutes() + ":" + dateObj.getSeconds() + "Z";
```

For the "July 17, 2008" part:

```
    var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    var dateObj = new Date(last_modified);
    var anotherDate = m_names[dateObj.getMonth()] + " " + dateObj.getDate() + ", " + dateObj.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Looks like I've overlooked some pretty cool string parsing abilities of native js Date object. I thought there was a fairly limited set of 'known' string formats that are accepted as constructor args. Nice

Comment: Pedant's note: it's inconvenient but unfortunately ECMAScript does not guarantee that the Date parser will be able to parse dates in RFC822 format as used by `Last-Modified`. It does work in all modern browsers, but you may be caught out by more obscure platforms.

Comment: @Rob: there is an extremely limited set of required-accepted string formats in the ECMAScript standard, almost to the point of complete uselessness. In reality, browsers implement much more than the standard requires, although exactly what they do and don't allow is variable and poorly-defined, which makes working with date parsing painful enough that you often end up doing it yourself (or with a library) anyway.

Comment: @Hasan Fahim - In the first conversion of Date to string, month needs to be +1. Also, do not assume UT.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). Might be a little more than you need but it is an awesome library. Code should look something like:

```
last_modified = xhr.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified');
last_modified_date = last_modified.split(': ')[1];
date = Date.parse(last_modified_date);
date.toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
```

**EDIT:** @Hasan has pointed out that the native Date object is capable of parsing the header text. For this simple task that is likely the best option.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Some browsers can natively return an ISO date string, but a lot cannot.
// And some insist on adding the milliseconds to the string-
// '2011-04-06T20:47:09.000Z'

    function isoString(date){
        var A, T, D= new Date(date);
        if(D){
        // uncomment next line if you allow msecs in string
        // if(D.toISOString) return D.toISOString();
            A= [D.getUTCFullYear(), D.getUTCMonth(), D.getUTCDate(),
            D.getUTCHours(), D.getUTCMinutes(), D.getUTCSeconds()];
            A[1]+= 1;
            for(var i= 0; i<6; i++)
            if(A[i]<10) A[i]= '0'+A[i];
            T= A.splice(3, A.length);
            return A.join("-")+("T" + T.join(":")+ "Z");
        }
        // throw 'bad date';
    }
```

var str='Wed, 06 Apr 2011 20:47:09 GMT';

**isoString(str)** returned value: (String) **2011-04-06T20:47:09Z**